# How To Project Texture With Molecular Script?

Tags: particles, shaders

I have been working on a project based on Molecular setup.

A rubik's cube(Source) just falling on plane(Emitter particles falling on plane from the rubik's cube).

I did all things correctly for simulation. But for the texturing setup I got stuck. I can't project the texture from rubik's cube to particles. I followed some youtube tutorials too.

You can find my setups on below image.
[image: Node setup of Emitter]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

Comment: Hi and welcome :)  I've made an edit to your Q to make it a bit easier to read, feel free to roll back the edit if you disagree with the changes I've made. It might be helpful to add a simplified copy of your [blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) with [all textures packed](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html#pack-all) so that other users that have molecular installed can take a closer look. Thanks :)